# How to run a verbatim search using MongoDB's Atlas Search

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to use MongoDB's Atlas Search to create a simple search engine.

I created an index for a field `source` that contains a long text in each document. Now I want to find all documents that contain exactly a specific string like "hello my name is".

So for example, a document with

```
source: "this is a long text and here comes hello my name is and here goes more text"
```

should be returned. But a document with

```
source: "this is another long text hi my name is and here goes even more text"
```

shouldn't be returned as the phrase doesn't appear exactly in the string.

So basically, what Google does when you run a [verbatim search](https://www.searchenginewatch.com/2011/11/18/google-introduces-verbatim-searching/).

When I'm using the following command with an index built using the [Standard Analyzer](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/analyzers/), I'm getting a lot of fuzzy results, i.e. documents where the source field only contains partial matches.

```
db.data.aggregate([
{
    '$search': {
        'index': 'default',
        'text': {'query': 'hello my name is','path': 'source'}
    }},
    {
        '$limit': 10
     },
     {  
         '$project': 
                    { '_id': 0,'source': 1}
      }
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use keyword analyzer for this field. It searches all search query string as a single term. If you need ability to use both, full match and similarity/partial match on same field, so you can setup muliple analyzers for one field. For example, **Standrt analyzer** for partial string match and **Keyword analyzer** for exact match

Check multiple analyzers index mapping example

```
  "description": {
    "analyzer": "lucene.simple",
    "multi": {
      "keywordAnalyzer": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.simple",
    "type": "string"
  }
```

Or just

```
  "description": {
    "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
    "type": "string"
  }
```